# Neo4j server not starting up:

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am using Neo4j 2.3.0-M03 community version. I have created a database using neo4j import tool. Now when I am going to start the neo4j server, its failing. Any advice? Thanks in advance!

Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [21597]... waiting for server to be ready......... Failed to start within 120 seconds.
Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.

The log is as follows:

```
2015-10-14 14:55:35.438-0400 INFO  No SSL certificate found, generating a self-signed certificate..
14:55:35.936 [main] DEBUG i.n.u.i.l.InternalLoggerFactory - Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
14:55:36.105 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Buffer.address: available
14:55:36.106 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
14:55:36.107 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
14:55:36.107 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Bits.unaligned: true
14:55:36.108 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - Java version: 7
14:55:36.108 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
14:55:36.109 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - sun.misc.Unsafe: available
14:55:36.109 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.noJavassist: false
14:55:36.110 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - Javassist: unavailable
14:55:36.110 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - You don't have Javassist in your class path or you don't have enough permission to load dynamically generated classes.  Please check the configuration for better performance.
14:55:36.110 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.tmpdir: /tmp (java.io.tmpdir)
14:55:36.110 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.bitMode: 64 (sun.arch.data.model)
14:55:36.110 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false
14:55:36.119 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetectionLevel: simple
14:55:36.135 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.allocator.type: unpooled
14:55:36.135 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.threadLocalDirectBufferSize: 65536
2015-10-14 14:55:41.341-0400 INFO  Successfully started database
2015-10-14 14:55:41.405-0400 INFO  Starting HTTP on port 7474 (32 threads available)
2015-10-14 14:55:41.659-0400 INFO  Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server
2015-10-14 14:55:42.224-0400 INFO  Successfully stopped database
2015-10-14 14:55:42.227-0400 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: tried to access field org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.RepresentationFormat.mediaType from class org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.RepresentationFormatRepository Starting Neo4j failed: tried to access field org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.RepresentationFormat.mediaType from class org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.RepresentationFormatRepository
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: tried to access field org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.RepresentationFormat.mediaType from class org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.RepresentationFormatRepository
        at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:67)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:234)
        at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:96)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.start(CommunityBootstrapper.java:48)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.main(CommunityBootstrapper.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.RepresentationFormat.mediaType from class org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.RepresentationFormatRepository
        at org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.RepresentationFormatRepository.<init>(RepresentationFormatRepository.java:46)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.createDefaultInjectables(AbstractNeoServer.java:641)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.configureWebServer(AbstractNeoServer.java:360)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:216)
        ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some permission issue on the lib folder of the Neo4j installation directory.
Try to give full permission to the neo4j installation folder.

Would also suggest to use stable version and not the milestone version.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But it was working fine before I  tried using Traversal API for implementing BFS traversal on my database. I created soft links of the Neo4j library files in my jdk lib folder in order to make them visible to my application. Then my code was running fine to get the traversal paths from the database. However, when I am again trying to run the server to try some cypher from the Neo4j-shell. It is giving this error.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it. There was some problem with my embedded database. I tried to run the server with its default graph.db and it run successfully. Now I have to identify what's wrong with the embedded database with I created using import tool.